# Change var depending on dropdown list index item JS

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, math, calculator

I'm trying to do a loan calculator where you can stimate the monthly playment value according to diferent interest and secures.

everything is working fine now, but then I was told that my `var S` variable depends on the type of credit.

that beign said:

```
var S = Y*0.00342
```

BUT

if items # `0,5,6,10,16` are selected in drop down list

THEN

my `var S` becomes

```
var S = Y*0.00042
```

so my question is:

How can I make this 'var s' to be depending on dropdownlist items?

how do I integrate this condition inside the function?

thanks in advance! :)

EDIT: here is the HTML list  --- value will be used in another `var`

```
<select id="list" >

<option value="2">Avance de nomina</option>
<option value="1.092">Calamidad</option>
<option value="1.292">Compra de vehiculo</option>
<option value="1.342">Compra de cartera</option>
<option value="1.292">Compra de moto nueva</option>
<option value="1.892">Consumo</option>
<option value="0.842">Crediaportes</option>
<option value="1.342">Cuota inicial compra vivienda nueva</option>
<option value="1.342">Educativo</option>
<option value="2.142">Electrodomestico</option>
<option value="2.042">Gerencia</option>
<option value="2.292">Ordinario con codeudor</option>
<option value="2.292">Ordinario sin codeudor</option>
<option value="1.342">Pago impuesto y reforma vivienda</option>
<option value="1.542">Prima</option>
<option value="1.942">Turismo y recreación</option>
<option value="1.892">Convenios y seguros</option>
</select>
```

here is the Function in Javascript

```
function INTERES() {          
var x = document.getElementById("list").value;   
var y = document.getElementById("valor").value;  
var c = document.getElementById("cuotas").value;    
var P = x/100;
var A = 1+P
var E = Math.pow(A, c)
var PE = P*E;
var I = E-1
var PEI = PE/I;
var T = y*PEI;
var G  = document.getElementById("list").selectedIndex
var S = y*0.00042;
var payment = T+S+2000;
document.getElementById("CALCULATOR").innerHTML = formatter.format(payment.toFixed());


}
```

var S will be used in function like

```
 Payment = T + S + 2000
```

EDIT 2:

I think im getting closer with this

```
var S= y*0.00342;
var G = document.getElementById("list").selectedIndex ;
if (G === ["0", "5", "6", "10", "16"]) { 
 S = y*0.00042;
}
```

maybe I have a syntaxis error? Im not sure how to proceed but would this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```js
var S = Y*0.00342

if ([0,5,6,10,16].includes(document.getElementById("list").selectedIndex)) {
  var S = Y*0.00042
}
```

Regardless of what you do, always make sure you sanitize anything you get from the DOM to maintain security.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I should have explain more into the list... I will edit

Comment: oh well! i still feel a little rookie about this.

so how should i write the variable? like

`var X = $("#list option:selected").val(); // for internal value 0, 1, 2, etc.`

Comment: We all start somewhere :) Don't sweat it. I've edited my answer to be what you're looking for, assuming you are using jQuery. If you have more questions, just comment back.

Comment: Ohh thanks a lot!!


so I should put index number inside ´.val(0,5,6,10,16)´ or where should be placed?

also, what do you mean by sanitize my inputs?

Comment: I added a second edit... maybe I could go that way and work somehow? I might have syntaxis problems

Comment: thank you! <3

Now i understand everything about it!